# Get letter corresponding to number in e (IEEE 1646)

Tags: specman, e

I want to convert from integer values to string characters as follows:

`0` to `"a"`

`1` to `"b"`

and so forth up to

`26` to `"z"`

Is there a way to do this in *e* without a big case statement?

Note: `e` is strongly typed and it isn't possible to do any type of arithmetic on string values. There also isn't any `char`-like type.

Another node: To all you C/C++ hotshots who keep down-voting my question, this isn't as easy a problem as you might think.

Comment: No idea about "e" but in general `char(97 + n)` where `char` returns a char from an ascii/unicode code

Comment: I know how to do it in C/C++ thank you very much. Why answer/downvote to questions where you have no idea?

Comment: I did not downvote, my comment was a comment, not an answer. I have no idea if you knew this or not - if you didn't my comment could be  quite useful, which after all is the point of this site.

Comment: @AlexK. Sorry, it must have been the guy who put the C++ answer up.

Comment: @Tudor, I guess probably because originally the question title didn't mention e, some people didn't realize what language it was about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
{0c"a"+my_num}.as_a(string)
```

`0c"a"` denotes the ASCII value of the letter 'a'. And an `as_a()` conversion of a list of numbers (actually, bytes) into a string creates a string where each character has the ASCII value of the corresponding list element.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for :D Is this mentioned in the documentation somewhere (I for one didn't find it)?

Comment: Yes, both points are mentioned in the documentation. The first one is mentioned in section about Literals and Constants ("Literal Character"). The second one is mentioned where as_a() and type conversions (between different combinations of types) are described.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new enum type to correspond to the alphabet, and use the fact that enum values are backed by int values to transform a list of ints to a list of enums, or to a string.

Consider the following example:

```
<'
type chars : [a, b, c, d, e, f, g];

extend sys {
    run() is also {
        var l : list of int[0..6];
        var s: string = "";

        gen l keeping {it.size() == 5};
        print l;
        for each in l { print it.as_a(chars); };

        for each in l { s = append(s, it.as_a(chars)); };
        print s;
    };
};        
'>
```

The output of this example will be:

```
  l = 
0.      4
1.      0
2.      6
3.      4
4.      5
  it.as_a(chars) = e
  it.as_a(chars) = a
  it.as_a(chars) = g
  it.as_a(chars) = e
  it.as_a(chars) = f
  s = "eagef"
```

Note that you can assign custom values to elements in the enum. In that way, you can assign standard ASCII values to enum elements.

```
 type chars : [a=10, b=11, c=12, d=13, e=14, f=15, g=16];
```

Comment: This is also conceptually similar to a big `case` statement, because we have to define the big `enum` ourselves. It's more elegant though, because it allows for conversions in both directions.